# Python Web API - Runaway queue times with Celery & RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, latency, low-latency

I built a python-based web API using nginx and uWSGI that handles approximately 100-200 RPS (requests per second) with a response time of 100-300ms. When an API request is received, the application triggers one or more back-end API calls to other data sources via geventHTTPclient and then aggregates data to respond to the initial request.

In a recent code upgrade, I offloaded these backend API calls to Celery (using libRabbitMQ as my broker). When I release this code to production, the results are initially acceptable--average response times increase slightly due to external latency from 2+ data sources, but application overhead time is roughly the same. However, over time I'm noticing a serious degradation of my API's latency of up to 10x the initial latency which is mainly due to increased queue time (see graph below). I've experimented with celery's configs and I am using the following:

```
CELERY_MAX_CACHED_RESULTS = -1
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=30
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD=5000
BROKER_URL = 'librabbitmq://guest@localhost//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT=1
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT=2
CELERYD_WORKER_LOST_WAIT=2
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER=16
```

I'm also running 4 uWSGI concurrently/pre-forked, with 10 concurrent/pre-forked celery workers. I'm noticing this also happens when I increase the number of celery workers to 16, but system resources (CPU) starts to max out.

Are there any other Celery/RabbitMQ parameters I can tune to try and improve this? The failed tasks appear to correlate with increased queue times, which may make sense given that workers become occupied with failed tasks and are unable to clear the queue. Almost like a cascading effect. Do I just need more workers on a better box?

[image: queue times]

**Update 1:** I ran a second test with the following settings and a slight modification on my app's code to reduce the load going to the queue. It appears it was running smoothly until some "event" happened roughly two hours into the test. Is there anything else I can use to monitor other aspects of the queue?

```
CELERY_MAX_CACHED_RESULTS = -1
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=10
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD=5000
BROKER_URL = 'librabbitmq://guest@localhost//'
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 2000
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT=1
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT=1.2
CELERYD_WORKER_LOST_WAIT=2
CELERYD_TIMER_PRECISION=0.1
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER=2
```

[image: update 1 latency]

**Update 2:** I increased the number of worker processes (3 workers with 10 concurrent threads `nohup celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=error --concurrency=10 -n worker1.%h &` ) and saw much more stability, however after about 2 hours a spike in API request errors occurred and caused a significant increase spike in latency on my app.

What's strange is that I have hard coded 3 levels of latency timeouts:

1. In my `geventhttpclient` HTTPClient (network_latency = .8s) at the
   task level
2. Celery's SoftTimeOut = 1.0s
3. Celery's (Hard)TimeOut = 1.2

In the event of failures, these caps should provide robust mitigation, but apparently not. I also tried to restart my celery workers on the fly, but that didn't work either.

[image]

**Update 3** - No luck when swapping out `geventhttpclient` as my HTTP request module and using just `httplib`. Also increased to `--concurrenty=18` for this trial. See picture below:

I'm pretty stuck at this point...

[image]

Comment: I'm also only using 1 worker. As it turns out my understanding of "concurrency" was a bit wrong, as "--concurency=10" flag in the celery worker command would only produce one worker with 10 threads. I'm going to test increasing the number of workers from 1 to 3.